# How to Compare Salesforce Contact email with All accounts related contact emails?

Tags: apex, soql

Here i have taken one "salesfore Contact" and "all Acounts related contacts"
   here i'm trying to compare all accounts related contacts email addresses with single salesforce Contact email addresses
   if any email matched and returning those accounts information.

here i have read the all acounts related contact information but i'm little confusing at comparing

this is my apex class

```
public class TestController {  
  @AuraEnabled
    public static void getInfo(){

       List<Account> accts = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account];//all acount related contact information
       Contact con = [select id,Name,email from Contact where email='test@gmail.com' limit 1];//single salesforce Contact

        for(Account a : accts){
           for(Contact c: a.contacts){

                System.debug('All Email'+c.email);
                here i get the all accounts contact emails.
                Now how can i compare test@gmail.com with all account related contacts emails

and returning those Account information 

            }

        }      
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just query for contacts with that email address pulling in the account info or gathering account ids then query for account info. Your current implementation is not scalable

Answer (score 0):

Please try this piece of code. Hope it will help you.

```
public class TestController {  
  @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getInfo(){

        List<Account> accts = new List<Account> ();
        Contact con = [select id,Name,AccountId,email from Contact where email='test@gmail.com' and AccountId !=null limit 1];
  if(con != null){
   accts = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account where Id=:con.AccountId];
   return accts;  
  }
    }
}
```